# Property or method (...) is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

> "Property or method **"show"** is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
>   either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property"

This is my code.

```js
<script>
import { SlideYUpTransition } from 'vue2-transitions'

export default {
  data: () => ({
    listitems: [{
        title: '출결관리',
        path: '/attendanceCheck'
      },
      {
        title: '학생관리',
        path: '/studentAdministration'
      },
      {
        title: '알림설정',
        path: '/notificationSetting'
      }
    ],
    components: {
      SlideYUpTransition
    },
    data() {
      return {
        show: true
      }
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>

/*-- Contents --*/
/* .content {
  width: 580px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
} */


@media ( max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }
  .content {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
</style>
```

```html
<template>

  <!-- Contents ( Image, Notice ) -->
  <div class = "contents">
    <section>
        <v-parallax src="/images/bg.png" height="650"></v-parallax>
    </section>
    <slide-y-up-transition  >
      <div v-show="show">Your content here</div>
    </slide-y-up-transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: In the first script you post, inside export default, I see two data function, I think you should use only one data function and put all the reactive data in there

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason for this error is that you might have used a "`model`" inside the "`template`" tag, but forgot to declare in the "data" section inside the "`script`" tag.

For Ex:

```html
<template>
    <el-form ref="form" :model="form" label-width="120px"> ##<=== form model used here
        <el-form-item label="Name">
            <el-input v-model="form.name"></el-input>
        </el-form-item>
  </el-form>
 </template>
```

But inside your "`Script`" tag you might have not used it

```js
export default {

  data: () => ({

      form:{
          name: ''   <----- Declare andd initialize here
          }

  }),


  methods:{

  },

  components: {

  }
};
```

This will solve your problem....

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your component should have `data` and `components` as top-level properties:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    listitems: [
      {
        title: '출결관리',
        path: '/attendanceCheck'
      },
      {
        title: '학생관리',
        path: '/studentAdministration'
      },
      {
        title: '알림설정',
        path: '/notificationSetting'
      }
    ],
    show: true
  }),
  components: {
    SlideYUpTransition
  }
}
```

`data` is a function that returns the state of the component, and `components` is an object.

Comment: don't think you should use fat arrow for data

Comment: Sure, it unnecessarily binds `this`, but does it break anything?

Comment: i thought it would, but it doesn't, dw!